# Is it correct to say "mind-blowingly"?

Tags: word-choice, adjectives

I wonder whether it would be correct say "mind-blowingly" in a sentence like this: "Mind-blowingly simple way to sell online".

Comment: Please include an example or two to show how you see this being used.

Comment: It would be used in a sentence "mind-blowingly simple way to sell online".

Comment: It's grammatically fine to say that something is "mind-blowingly simple". Whether that is an accurate description in the circumstances is a matter of opinion.